# Batch force windows calculator to close in Windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have three monitors, and I like to play SMITE in triple surround. To do this the NVIDIA Control Panel wants me to close a few (to me random) applications before it can do its magic. This is all good and well, but the calculator application is a pain to close. I have to use the task manager to force the process to stop, because for some reason it doesn't always by itself.

I want to use a batch script for this, so it will close automatically with only a single double click (along with some other applications that sometimes do and sometimes don't need to be closed)

But since the calculator isn't just a simple .exe, I can't figure out how to shut it down. What I've found for a regular process is `taskkill /f /im processname.exe` but, the calculator doesn't have a simple .exe I can kill. The default Windows 10 apps have odd names, and are technically file folders according to their properties.

Can somebody help me with how to kill the Windows apps processes via batch (or something else if that's better)?

Comment: the calculator is a normal exe as far as I know.`taskkill /im calc.exe` kills it on my machine.

Comment: When you want to test it out ofcourse you can't get the process to remain in the background... Murphy's law in reversed :p I believe I've already tried this once, but it doesn't work because of the folder thing and it not being a exe... Are you running Windows 10? In earlier versions the folder thing wasn't the case as far as I'm aware.

Comment: So you are saying that task list does not show the imagename as calculator.exe?

Comment: I finally have the issue again. Let me make some screenshots, and test your suggestions :)

Comment: Since I can't edit my previous comment I'll put it here.  (...) 

Well, maybe I should have made the screenshots of the process before trying out the suggestions... :p @Squashman Well, I know for a fact that it looked like the weather application one. There it states that it's name is `Microsoft.BingWeather_4.17.74.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe`, and has `File Folder (.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe)` as type. Not the .exe I'd expect to kill. I'm not quite sure what you mean by imagename, but it shows in the pattern I described for the weather application.

Comment: @MagicLegend, if you actually read the help for the `TASKKILL` and `TASKLIST` commands you should most definitely know what imagename means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Calculator's executable is located (for me) at

`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1611.3123.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
\calculator.exe`

that program is launched by `calc.exe`. You can terminate Windows Calculator with:

```
taskkill /f /im calculator.exe
```

Comment: Can confirm, `taskkill /f /im calculator.exe` kills the Calculator in Windows 10.

Comment: Hehe, didn't try the full English word. My Windows apps are Dutch, so I tried `rekenmachine.exe` (Calculator in Dutch). This indeed actually terminates the correct process. Now I have to add a few more apps (Weather is also a troublemaker sometimes), and I'm ready to go :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: if I saw a process called `rekenmachine.exe` running on my computer I'd freak out. (:

Answer (score 1):

Instead use `Stop-Process -Name calculator`

Comment: Hi! I am not super familiar with the Windows scripting, but I was specifically after Batch here - not PowerShell, which I believe your command is. Still a useful contribution for those looking for a PS solution!

Answer (score 0):

Calculator application's process name has been changed to calculatorApp.exe.
To kill the calculator the command would be:

```
taskkill /F /IM calculatorApp.exe
```

Comment: interesting: You still execute `calc.exe`, which in turn seems to run `calculatorApp.exe`, which does not even exist (or is in a non-accessible folder). Microsoft-magic...  `:/` (this solution works on both Win10 and Win11)